# ios , how to change the image and hide title when the button is changed to the selected state?

Tags: ios, uibutton

how to change the image and hide title when the button is changed to the selected state?

normal state:

[image]

Selected State:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the title of button is static, you could have 2 image: one with image and title and another with just image and do something like this.

```
yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"imageandtitle.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"imageonly.png"),forState:UIControlState.Selected)
```

Later you can write the function of button as follows,

```
@IBAction btnTapAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.selected{
         sender.selected = false
    }
    else{
        sender.selected = true
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code for objective-c ,but  you must import the sdwebimage.

```
NSString *imgUrl1 = @"https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWblQ.png";
NSString *imgUrl2 = @"https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcdTa.png";
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100, 100)];
    btn.center = self.view.center;

    [btn sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl2] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];


- (void)btnSelect:(UIButton *)select{
    select.selected = !select.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"imageandtitle.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"imageonly.png"),forState:UIControlState.Selected)
yourBtn.setTitle("abc",forState:UIControlState.Normal)
yourBtn.setTitle("",forState:UIControlState.Selected)
```